# Can we have Ui for cloudfoundry deployed on AWS

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

Iam new to Cloudfoundry on AWS. I have deployed cloudfoundry on AWS, but when i want to push an application into cf which i have deployed i was using command line tool (cf). Is there any way we have UI like Cloudfoundry where we can check our app running on UI , and even on Bluemix we can have ace.ng.bluemix.net to login and check our apps.

I want to know if i can check my appp deployed in my custom cloudfoundry deployed on AWS in UI where i can see other applications as well running.

It would be very helpful if i get this.

Thanks & regards,

Srilatha K.

Answer (score 3):

There is the admin-ui, which is a bit more detailed than the Pivotal WS/CF interface but will provide you a BUI as an alternative to cf cli:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/admin-ui

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of BOSH.
It takes care of deployment & life cycles managements...

Reference - http://www.slideshare.net/ManuelGarcia122/cloud-foundry-handson-deployment-workshop
Slide 29 onwards

Useful link - http://blog.altoros.com/tag/cloud-foundry